# Ubuntu installing issue ATI video card laptop

Tags: drivers, ati, gpu-driver

Todays is my second day I'm trying to install ubuntu on laptop. Decided to write here.

Laptop Samsung r538 has Ati radeon 4500 series, googling arround I found that it's the problem.

So I'm trying to install 15.4 from live usb - Live version don't run, it shows me the violet diamond wallpaper and then says that the system encounted an error.

Upon install, I got a grub error Gave up waiting for root device and says that ID of my HHD not found.

I tried to install 14.4 from usb. Live version goes to login loop. Upon install it shows me the violet diamond wallpaper and then says that the system encounted an error. And nothing happens more.

I also tryied Mint, live cd was running OK, after install it stucks on mint logo. I guess it's a driver issue, but how I can change them before installing?

Comment: PS. I'm dual boot with win 7, it works